# Flutter Barcode Scanner for Window

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using flutter package

> barcode_scan: any

for scanning barcode using my scanner to record data using flutter desktop support, but this extension asking me for camera even i have scanner to scan barcode
code sample that i am using.

````
      ScanResult barcodez = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
     setState(() {
            barcode = barcodez as String;
          });
       }```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello barcode_Scanner only works with android and iOS, It is written in the packages details.

Also the package is made undertaking the camera feature and not the actually barcode scanner.